# Multiple svg with same IDs

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Can i put multiple svgs in a html page and use the same IDs in all of them?

```
<div>
  <svg height="0" width="0">
    <clipPath id="svgPath"> ........        
  </svg>
  <svg height="0" width="0">
    <clipPath id="svgPath"> ........        
  </svg>
  <svg height="0" width="0">
    <clipPath id="svgPath"> ........        
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: ID's must always be unique.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the specs define the `id` attribute as unique per document, you should refactor the IDs or use an alternative, e.g. embedding via `img` or `object` tag.

```
<img src="my.svg" height="100" alt="alternative Text">

<object type="image/svg+xml" data="my.svg" width="100" height="100"></object>
```

Comment: But an SVG image _is_ a document, too.

Comment: @КонстантинВан Yes, but when inlined into an HTML document it inhererits the SVG ids. The same problem can occur with inline iframe documents.

Answer (score 8):

If you need the SVGs to be inline you should consider using an SVG injector, which changes the IDs to unique strings when inserting the SVGs into the HTML document

[SVGInject](https://github.com/iconfu/svg-inject) adds a random string to the end of the ID for elements defined in the `<defs>` section. For example, `svgPath` may become something like `svgPath-Dcs83KsE`. Other SVG injectors add a running number to the ID.

Both methods were developed so the same SVG can be injected multiple times into a HTML document without creating an ID conflict. But of course it also works for different SVGs with conflicting IDs.

Answer (score -2):

You can't write multiple id attribute in your html. Id attribute must be unique in html document.

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's.
>
> https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute

You need to use class attribute for your purpose.

Comment: That's a very bad spec to reference for this. HTML 4.01 doesn't allow the `<svg>` element in the first place.

Comment: The reference is for HTML 5

Comment: It wasn't when the comment was made. The edit history is clear. (And a 2011 draft of HTML 5 isn't a good reference now and wasn't in 2016 either).

Comment: @Quentin I know this, but user doesn't check reference url and voting down me for your old comment. So i posted comment to prevent it.